# Bitbucket pipeline for nginx server which is on Ubuntu vm

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using nginx for hosting angular application on ubuntu vm which is on Azure.
I want to create pipeline for easy deployment. I have tried "azure-vm-linux-script-deploy:1.0.1" pipe, but it requires APP-ID and we don't have web app. Is there any other configuration I need to do into this ?

Also, I have tried "atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.6" pipe. But it is giving error of 'connection timeout'.

I have SSH installed on vm and it is in active mode, ssh port is 22 and it is open. And there is no firewall restriction.

This is my yml file

```
  pipelines:
    default:
     - step:
         name: Deploy to production
         deployment: production
         script:
           - echo "Deploying to production environment"
           - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.6
             variables:
               SSH_USER: 'root'
               SERVER: '**.***.**.**'
               COMMAND: '/home/deployscript.sh'
```

I am getting the below error every time.

```
ssh: connect to host **.***.**.** port 22: Operation timed out
✖ Execution failed.
```

*note: i have replaced the host with * here for security.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer,

Actually, the App ID required there for "azure-vm-linux-script-deploy:1.0.1" pipe, is for the service principal.
It was not of a Web App.
So I referred to this documentation on how to create a service principal. - https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-to-microsoft-azure/

Hope this can be helpful to anyone in future!